# Libraries to convert obvious mathematical syntax to an equation/image?

Tags: python, math, wolframalpha

Are there any libraries (Python) that are able to convert obvious mathematical notation in basic string form to an appropriate equation in LaTeX or an image format? Think Wolfram|Alpha, where you type in some mathematical syntax and it is able to generate an estimate of what it would look like if written in mathematical notation, most of the time being correct. For example, it should be able to convert something like:

```
r * 2pi + 10^sqrt(2) * log(10) - (9^(1/3) / 5)
```

into:

> [image: r * 2pi + 10^sqrt(2) * log(10) - (9^(1/3) / 5)]

Optionally, it also needs to parse a block of text and pick out mathematical bits and pieces. For example, this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor r * 2pi +10^sqrt(2) sit amet, log(10) lorem -(9^(1/3) / 5)
```

becomes:

> Lorem ipsum dolor [image: r * 2pi +10^sqrt(2)] sit amet, [image: log(10)] lorem [image: -(9^(1/3) / 5)]

Ideally, it would support as much mathematical notation as possible. For example, sets, matrices/vectors, integrals, et cetera.

Do any packages exist that meet the above requirements? Are there any open source ones? Thank you in advance. =)

**EDIT:** I do *NOT* want to render LaTeX on a webpage. I have not said that anywhere. I am aware of how to do that. That is not what I am after. I simply asked if there are any *Python* libraries that can take basic mathematical syntax and output mathematical notation in the syntax/form of LaTeX *or* an image. See my examples for what I mean. And see Wolfram|Alpha if you still don't get it (where you don't need to type in TeX syntax to get an appropriate equation-image produced).

Comment: Take a look at mathplotlib, especially with bindings related to LaTeX (that is what you are looking for): http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html

Comment: @Jack No it isn't? That requires me to use TeX markup to render mathematical notation, and thus must explicitly state the symbols and format used, which is something that I don't want.

Comment: Questions about recommending tools, library and such are off-topic for this site, remember?

Comment: @alKid I see. I was not aware, sorry, as I see questions such as these  pop up all the time on this website. However, I do not think it breaks the rule as such, as I highly doubt there can be any opinionated responses to my *explicit* question. Thank you for bringing it to my attention, though.

Comment: @Mayazcherquoi: and what do you want? You surely need a syntax to describe equations, or are you looking for something that is able to guess that that's an equation and render it? LaTeX markup for equations is as much straightforward as it is, a learning curve would be required in any case. If you need something that is able to 'guess' or that MUST use the specific syntax you want (since you complain about a different syntax) then I guess you should write your own. Even Wolfram uses a specific syntax with a given learning curve, see `sqrt` or `^`.

Comment: @Mayazcherquoi Take a look at Sage [1] which is a math program implemented in Python and which can render equations (among other things). As for mixing math and text, I think they have something called the "notebook" which can do that. You can get more info about Sage on the sage-support user forum [2]. Refs: [1] http://www.sagemath.org/ [2] https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/sage-support